# CSS: max-width no funciona

Tags: html, css, css3

Estoy haciendo un formulario de pago, pero estoy teniendo problemas con la parte del diseño, en especial cuando cambia el tamaño de la pantalla la clase "formas" no respeta el cambio del max-width.

Esta es la vista desde un escritorio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=divice-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>    
<title>Compras</title>
<style>
  .StripeElement {
    background-color: white;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
    transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
  }

  .StripeElement--focus {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
  }

  .StripeElement--invalid {
    border-color: #fa755a;
  }

  .StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
    background-color: #fefde5 !important;
  }

</style>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 formas2">
    <a href="mi_cuenta.php">
      Regresar
    </a>
    <br>
    <h3 class="h2">Compra</h3>
    <div align="center">
      <table>
        <tr class="headt">
          <th><h5 class="h3">Producto</h5></th>
          <th><h5 class="h3">Cantidad</h5></th>
          <th><h5 class="h3">Precio</h5></th>
          <th><h5 class="h3">IVA</h5></th>
          <th><h5 class="h3">Total</h5></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="text-dark-75">Membresía Bronce</p></td>
          <td><p class="text-dark-75">1</p></td>
          <td><p class="text-dark-75">$500.00</p></td>
          <td><p class="text-dark-75">$52.40</p></td>
          <td><p class="text-dark-75">$552.40</p></td>
        </tr>            
      </table>
    </div>
    <div>
      Aquí va otra cosa
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 formas">
    <h3 class="h2">Pago con tarjeta</h3>
    <form action="create-session.php" method="post" id="payment-form">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div>
          <label for="card-element">
            <p class="text-dark">Correo electrónico</p>
          </label>
          <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Ej. juan@ejemplo.com" name="email" id="email"/>
        </div>
        <label for="card-element">
          <p class="text-dark">Información de la tarjeta</p>              
        </label>
        <div id="card-element">
          <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
        </div>
        <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
        <div>
          <label for="card-element">
            <p class="text-dark">Nombre en la tarjeta</p>                 
          </label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Ej. Juan Perez Hidalgo" name="nombre" id="nombre"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="card-element">
            <p class="text-dark">País o región</p>              
          </label>
          <select name="pais" class="form-control-select" id="pais" required="">
            <option value="">Seleccione el país</option>
            <option value="">----------------------</option>
            <option value="">Principales países:</option>
            <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
            <option value="México">México</option>
            <option value="España">España</option>
            <option value="Estados Unidos">Estados Unidos</option>
            <option value="">----------------------</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <input type="hidden"  id="id_cliente" name="id_cliente" value=$id_cliente>
      <input type="hidden"  id="costo" name="costo" value=$precio>
      <p class="h2">Subtotal: $$siniva.00 MXN</p>
      <p class="h2">IVA: $$iva.$extra MXN</p>
      <h3 class="h2">Total: $$costos.$extra MXN</h3>
      <div align="center">
        <button class="btn">Pagar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.

var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    lineHeight: '18px',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

</script>
</html>
```

Este es el código CSS

```
body {  
 background: #efeff5;
 background-size: 100vw 100vh; 
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 margin-right: -15px;
 margin-left: -15px; 
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.col-lg-6 {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 -webkit-box-flex: 0;
 -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
 flex: 0 0 50%;
 max-width: 50%; 
 background-color:white;
}

.formas2{
  height: 665px;  /*Cambiar*/
  max-width: 45%; /*Cambiar*/
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 6px; 
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.formas{
  height: 665px; /*Cambiar*/
  max-width:45%; /*Cambiar*/
  margin: auto;  
  border-radius: 6px;  
  border-left: 1px solid #EBEDF3;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.h2 {        
  color:#363636;
  opacity: 1;  
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.h3 {        
  color:#fcfcfc;
  opacity: 1;  
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.form-control { 
 background-color: white;
 height: 40px;
 width: 95%;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
 -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
 transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
 font-size: 1.05rem;
 color: #373a4b
}
.form-control--focus {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.form-control--invalid {
 border-color: #fa755a;
}

.form-control--webkit-autofill {
 background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #B5B5C3;
 opacity: 1; 
 font-size: 1.06rem;
}
.form-control-select { 
 background-color: white;
 height: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
 -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
 transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
 font-size: 1.05rem;
 color: #373a4b
}
.form-control-select--focus {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.form-control-select--invalid {
 border-color: #fa755a;
}

.form-control-select--webkit-autofill {
 background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}
.form-control-select::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #B5B5C3;
 opacity: 1; 
 font-size: 1.06rem;
}
.btn{
 background-color: #4CAF50; /* verde */
 border: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px 40px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
 width: 100%;
}
table {
 width: 100%;        
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
 width: 25%;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: center;
 border: 1px solid  #dcdde2;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 padding: 0.3em;
 caption-side: bottom;
}
.headt {
 min-width: 235px;
 height: 10px;
 background-color: #8950FC;
}

.text-dark {
 color: #181C32 !important; 
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.text-dark-75 {
 color: #181C32 !important; 
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
}


@media (max-width:415px) {

 .formas2{
  height: 300px;  /*Cambia*/
  max-width: 401px; /*Cambia*/
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 6px; 
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
 }
 .formas{
  height: 665px; /*Cambia*/
  max-width: 400px; /*Error*/
  margin: auto;  
  border-radius: 6px;  
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
 }
}
```

Este es el resultado.
La clase formas en @media(max-width:415px) no toma el max-width establecido, solo modifica su tamaño de  10px hasta 225px.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que se ajuste al ancho de la pantalla, pero no me respeta el width.
La clase formas2 que es literalmente lo mismo si hace el cambio de dimensiones, pero la clase formas no lo hace.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es max-width o min-width la propiedad que estás buscando?

Comment: Hola! Es max-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Va el codigo entero. Lo que hice fue agregarle Bootstrap, y cambiarle estilos, que estaban funcionando mal. Tambien cambie la tabla para que sea full width.

```css
<style>
  .StripeElement {
    background-color: white;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
    transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
  }

  .StripeElement--focus {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
  }

  .StripeElement--invalid {
    border-color: #fa755a;
  }

  .StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
    background-color: #fefde5 !important;
  }

</style>

<style type="text/css">
    body {  
 background: #efeff5;
 background-size: 100vw 100vh; 
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.formas2{
  height: 665px;  /*Cambiar*/
  max-width: 45%; /*Cambiar*/
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 6px; 
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col-lg-6 {
 background-color:white;
}


.formas{
  height: 665px; /*Cambiar*/
  max-width:45%; /*Cambiar*/
  margin: auto;  
  border-radius: 6px;  
  border-left: 1px solid #EBEDF3;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.h2 {        
  color:#363636;
  opacity: 1;  
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.h3 {        
  color:#fcfcfc;
  opacity: 1;  
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.form-control { 
 background-color: white;
 height: 40px;
 width: 95%;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
 -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
 transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
 font-size: 1.05rem;
 color: #373a4b
}
.form-control--focus {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.form-control--invalid {
 border-color: #fa755a;
}

.form-control--webkit-autofill {
 background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #B5B5C3;
 opacity: 1; 
 font-size: 1.06rem;
}
.form-control-select { 
 background-color: white;
 height: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
 -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
 transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
 font-size: 1.05rem;
 color: #373a4b
}
.form-control-select--focus {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.form-control-select--invalid {
 border-color: #fa755a;
}

.form-control-select--webkit-autofill {
 background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}
.form-control-select::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #B5B5C3;
 opacity: 1; 
 font-size: 1.06rem;
}
.btn{
 background-color: #4CAF50; /* verde */
 border: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px 40px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
 width: 100%;
}


   table{
        width:100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }

th, td {
 width: 25%;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: center;
 border: 1px solid  #dcdde2;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 padding: 0.3em;
 caption-side: bottom;
}
.headt {
 min-width: 235px;
 height: 10px;
 background-color: #8950FC;
}

.text-dark {
 color: #181C32 !important; 
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.text-dark-75 {
 color: #181C32 !important; 
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
}




@media (max-width:415px) {

 .formas2{
  height: 300px;  /*Cambia*/
  max-width: 401px; /*Cambia*/
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 6px; 
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
 }

 .row{
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
 }

 .formas{
  height: 665px; /*Cambia*/
  max-width: 400px; /*Error*/
  margin: auto;  
  border-radius: 6px;  
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
 }
}
</style>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=divice-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Compras</title>



</head>
<body>
 <section>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 formas2">
    <a href="mi_cuenta.php">
      Regresar
    </a>
    <br>
    <h3 class="h2">Compra</h3>
    <div style="width:100%">
      <table>
        <tr class="headt">
          <th><h5 class="h3">Producto</h5></th>
          <th><h5 class="h3">Cantidad</h5></th>
          <th><h5 class="h3">Precio</h5></th>
          <th><h5 class="h3">IVA</h5></th>
          <th><h5 class="h3">Total</h5></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="text-dark-75">Membresía Bronce</p></td>
          <td><p class="text-dark-75">1</p></td>
          <td><p class="text-dark-75">$500.00</p></td>
          <td><p class="text-dark-75">$52.40</p></td>
          <td><p class="text-dark-75">$552.40</p></td>
        </tr>            
      </table>
    </div>
    <div>
      Aquí va otra cosa
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 formas">
    <h3 class="h2">Pago con tarjeta</h3>
    <form action="create-session.php" method="post" id="payment-form">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div>
          <label for="card-element">
            <p class="text-dark">Correo electrónico</p>
          </label>
          <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Ej. juan@ejemplo.com" name="email" id="email"/>
        </div>
        <label for="card-element">
          <p class="text-dark">Información de la tarjeta</p>              
        </label>
        <div id="card-element">
          <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
        </div>
        <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
        <div>
          <label for="card-element">
            <p class="text-dark">Nombre en la tarjeta</p>                 
          </label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Ej. Juan Perez Hidalgo" name="nombre" id="nombre"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="card-element">
            <p class="text-dark">País o región</p>              
          </label>
          <select name="pais" class="form-control-select" id="pais" required="">
            <option value="">Seleccione el país</option>
            <option value="">----------------------</option>
            <option value="">Principales países:</option>
            <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
            <option value="México">México</option>
            <option value="España">España</option>
            <option value="Estados Unidos">Estados Unidos</option>
            <option value="">----------------------</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <input type="hidden"  id="id_cliente" name="id_cliente" value=$id_cliente>
      <input type="hidden"  id="costo" name="costo" value=$precio>
      <p class="h2">Subtotal: $$siniva.00 MXN</p>
      <p class="h2">IVA: $$iva.$extra MXN</p>
      <h3 class="h2">Total: $$costos.$extra MXN</h3>
      <div align="center">
        <button class="btn">Pagar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
   </div>
 </section> 

</body>

<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<script>

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.

var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    lineHeight: '18px',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: No puedo agregar Bootstrap, porque me quita el campo de la tarjeta, pero al leer tu respuesta encontré la parte que estaba provocando el error. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tengo un problema parecido pero al final no me entere cual es la razón por la cual no funciono el max-width